# How can I add roles in mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, roles, asp.net-mvc-5.1, asp.net-roles

How can I add roles in a empty mvc 5 project?

I searched on google but I don't found a tutorial for an **empty** project.

Can someone give me a link to a tutorial or help me here ?

Comment: http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/06/22/ASPNET-Identity-20-Customizing-Users-and-Roles.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
if (!roleManager.RoleExists("RoleName"))
{
      var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
      role.Name = "RoleName";
      roleManager.Create(role);
}
```